# How to Create a mailbox in Exchange 2010 with Linux

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

How do I create from a linux server (with winexe installed) a new mailbox for a user that's already known in Active Directory? When I try the following:

```
./winexe -U <Domain>/<DomainAdminUser%Password> //<ip address of exchange server> 'Powershell -Command Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010;Enable-Mailbox -Identity <Domain>\<UsernameToCreateMailboxFor> -Database \"<MailDatabase>\"'
```

I get the following error, probably because of insufficient permissions.

```
Enable-Mailbox : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: parameters
At line:1 char:75
+ Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.E2010;Enable-Mailbox <<
<<  -Identity <domain>\<UsernameToCreateMailboxFor> -Database "<MailDatabase>"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-Mailbox], ArgumentNull
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentNullException,Microsoft.Exchange.
   Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMailbox
```

**Edit**
Some background information:

I'm creating a simplified web interface for user creation so non-IT personnel is able to create a new user. I do have only access to a Linux server to host the web application. Active Directory is easily managable with ldap, but for exchange you have to resort to these tricks.

Comment: What?!? Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: I'm interested if you know a better way from creating a mailbox in Exchange from a linux server?

Comment: Exchange 2010 already has a [control panel web application](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/using-exchange-control-panel-ecp-manage-exchange-organization-part1.html) - why would you reinvent the wheel?

Comment: But that's not what I want, I don't want to rebuild the exchange interface in a web interface. I simply want to create a mailbox with a script running from a linux server.

Comment: May I ask why you think that the problem is permissions when the error says that a parameter is null? I can definitely forsee permissions problems with this, and I can think of a few ways you might overcome those, but for now I wonder if we might get past the ArgumentNullException. To that end, I think you should look into the `-EncodedCommand` parameter of powershell.exe. It may be that somewhere along the way your `-Command` string is getting mangled, and using `-EncodedCommand` is a good way to prevent that.